# Sending Request and Get Response

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a php code running on my server that i call my web service.It processes the data in send integer value.How can i get that?Here is my request url :

```
  NSString *requestURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?u=%@&  p=%@&platform=ios",url,txtUserName.text,txtPassword.text];
```

Update Comment : I have a php file on my server.It takes 3 arguments and register my users and returns value like 1(for success,2 for duplicate).I need to send request to my server as :

```
url="http://smwebtech.com/Pandit/web_service/signup.php?u=Test&p=password&platform=ios"
```

How can i send this request to server and get the return value from server?

Comment: Would you mind explaining your issue a bit more? Do you want to know how to make the HTTP request to your server?

Comment: Which kind of the encode you can do on the server side json or direct xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use NSURLConnection. You should use implement the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol and use the `NSURLConnection` class.

```
-(void) requestPage
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://the.page.you.want.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:20.0f];


    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] retain];
    delegate = target;
}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{   
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response; 
        //If you need the response, you can use it here
    }
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [responseData release];
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (connection == adCheckConnection)
    {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //You've got all the data now
        //Do something with your response string


        [responseString release];
    }

    [responseData release];
    [connection release];
}
```

Comment: The connection isn't guaranteed to return the data all at once. `responseData` collects this information until the connection has finished returning all the data and in my example I convert it to a string.

Comment: The final value is the value returned in `connectionDidFinishLoading` and as a string, it's the value I converted to a string

Comment: yes the didFinish method was not in your previous update..i figured it out..thanks for your response and proepr guideline...

Comment: I haven't made any edits otherwise there would be an edited link. Are you sure you didn't just scroll down far enough! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to make HTTP requests to a server, there's a number of frameworks that's helping you do that. Up until recently, [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) was the one i favored, but unfortunately it's been discontinued.

[Google's API Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) is also a good option, as well as a [number of others suggested](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;) by the creator of ASIHTTPRequest.

There should be plenty of docs in there to get you started.

**EDIT:** To make your specific request with `ASIHTTPRequest`, do the following in a class with the protocol `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate`:

```
/**
 * Make a request to the server.
 */
- (void) makeRequest {
    // compile your URL string and make the request
    NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?u=%@&  p=%@&platform=ios", url, txtUserName.text, txtPassword.text];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestURL];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

/**
 * Handle the response from the previous request.
 * @see ASIHTTPRequestDelegate
 */
- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request {
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    // do whatever you need with the response, i.e. 
    // convert it to a JSON object using the json-framework (https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. visit [HTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions)  and setup it in your project according to given instructins.
2. [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) - download and put it in your project.
3. below are the methods you can use for sending request, and getting response.

   ```
     -(void) SendAsyncReq:(NSString *)urlString 
      {


   NSLog(@"URL IS: %@",urlString);
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString     stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


   ASIHTTPRequest *request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

   [request1 setDelegate:self];


       [request1 startAsynchronous];
   }

     /// THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED IF REQUEST IS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY

    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)response
   {
   NSData *responseData = [response responseData];

   CJSONDeserializer *jsonDeserializer = [CJSONDeserializer   deserializer];

   NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [jsonDeserializer  deserializeAsDictionary:responseData error:nil];

   NSLog(@"Response is: %@",resultsDictionary);


       }

    /// THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED IF REQUEST IS FAILED DUE TO SOME REASON.

   - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)response
   {
   NSError *error = [response error];
   NSLog(@"%d", [error code]);
   if([error code] !=4)
   {
       NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                           message:errorMessage
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];
       [alertView release];
   }



   }
   ```

you must import #import "CJSONDeserializer.h" and #import "ASIHTTPRequest.h" in your class.
I hope this will help.

Comment: I opened the url, and its simply printing HTML.. this will not work.. you have to make either XML or JSON.  that u'll parse at iphone end. In my answer i provided code to get response , and parse json.