# When is applicationDidBecomeActive called?

Tags: ios

When does the method `applicationDidBecomeActive` get called? What is the purpose of this method?

Comment: read about the App lifeCycle https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: explain me ... applicationDidBecomeActive:—Lets your app know that it is about to become the foreground app. Use this method for any last minute preparation.

Comment: That means that the app was in backgroun and you select the app to come to foreground.

Comment: if u r minize your app and open the call or any other app -- thats time your app is background mode, then you click the app in that time it open the last seen the page in your app -- this is called foreground in this time the (applicationDidBecomeActive) method is called.

Comment: thank u i understood ..also explain me about applicationWillResignActive method

Comment: That is the state, wenn you minimize the app.

Comment: use of this method????- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url

Comment: Just a general best practices comment. Why don't you store the object returned from `[AppData getObject]` in a variable rather than constantly calling the same functionality?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Understand the states and transitions of an iOS**

**States**

**Non-running** - The app is not running.

**Inactive** - The app is running in the foreground, but not receiving events. An iOS app can be placed into an inactive state, for example, when a call or SMS message is received.

**Active** - The app is running in the foreground, and receiving events.

**Background** - The app is running in the background, and executing code.

**Suspended** - The app is in the background, but no code is being executed.

**The seven most important application delegate methods**

> > The operating system calls specific methods within the application delegate to facilitate transitioning to and from various states. The seven most important application delegate methods a developer should handle are:

**application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

> > Method called when the launch process is initiated. This is the first opportunity to execute any code within the app.

**application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

> > Method called when the launch process is nearly complete. Since this method is called is before any of the app's windows are displayed, it is the last opportunity to prepare the interface and make any final adjustments.

**applicationDidBecomeActive**

> > Once the application has become active, the application delegate will receive a callback notification message via the method applicationDidBecomeActive.
> >
> > This method is also called each time the app returns to an active state from a previous switch to inactive from a resulting phone call or SMS.

**applicationWillResignActive**

> > There are several conditions that will spawn the applicationWillResignActive method. Each time a temporary event, such as a phone call, happens this method gets called. It is also important to note that "quitting" an iOS app does not terminate the processes, but rather moves the app to the background.

**applicationDidEnterBackground**

> > This method is called when an iOS app is running, but no longer in the foreground. In other words, the user interface is not currently being displayed. According to Apple's UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference, the app has approximately five seconds to perform tasks and return. If the method does not return within five seconds, the application is terminated.

**applicationWillEnterForeground**

> > This method is called as an app is preparing to move from the background to the foreground. The app, however, is not moved into an active state without the applicationDidBecomeActive method being called. This method gives a developer the opportunity to re-establish the settings of the previous running state before the app becomes active.

**applicationWillTerminate**

> > This method notifies your application delegate when a termination event has been triggered. Hitting the home button no longer quits the application. Force quitting the iOS app, or shutting down the device triggers the applicationWillTerminate method. This is the opportunity to save the application configuration, settings, and user preferences.

need additional information ref this [link1](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/understand-the-states-and-transitions-of-an-ios-app/) or apple [link2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/)

Comment: handleOpenURL  -- this is used for custom URL Schema, when it used if u want to redirect the app/open the app if user click the link example -- http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: have a nice day my sister, have a nice day and bye

Comment: can we use different font size such as: WITH RESPECT TO MOBILE INFORMATION OR USE THEREOF, PROVIDES CONTENT, ACCESS TO, AND USE OF MOBILE "AS IS", AND EXPRESSLY DISCLAIMS ANY AND ALL WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTIBILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. You agree </br>
as in html?

Comment: you can't change the fonts or settings of apple provided messages, in side your you can do everything and anything is possible,.

Comment: how to send request and get response using an url

Comment: in here there are several methods, r u asking synchronous or asynchronous

Comment: using synchronous with background [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928401/sending-request-and-get-response)  synchronous with foreground use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480590/send-parameter-for-php-and-wait-for-response)

Comment: help me out in creating a simple login page with username password and submit button

Comment: simple na, in here what u need -- it taken only 10 minutes works

Comment: k , send the code, which one u need auto layout or auto resizing in design format

Comment: Good answer, you can use them to deal with notifications also

Answer (score 2):

When a user is using an application he is in an active state. The user switch to inactive state from a resulting phone call or when a pull down notification center is pulled or when the home screen is pressed(This is when the app is told to be in background state) and then the app is opened again(This is when the app is told to be back to foreground state).

So every time the user switches from inactive state to active state 
applicationDidBecomeActive this delegate is called

Comment: what is the use of - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Comment: This is got to do with the inter app communication. So basically The implementation of your application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method should retrieve the URL from its options dictionary and determine whether the app can open it. If it can, return YES and let your - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url –  handle it. If you are returning NO the this delegate is not called at all