# Calling a Web Service with a warped JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, json, web-services, rest

I use this type of function to call my Web Services from my iOS App:

```
-(NSData *)getMainMenuJsonData{
    NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@/%@",[configs valueForKey:@"wsURL"], [configs valueForKey:@"clientToken"], [configs valueForKey:@"appToken"], [CommonsUtils getCommonUtil].getAppLanguage];

    NSString* webStringURL = [urlAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:2.5];
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSUInteger statusCode = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode;

    if (statusCode == 200 && error == Nil) {
        if (error != Nil) {
            return Nil;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
    else {
        return Nil;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, I'm sending something like:

http://myserver.com/WSFunction/Parameter1/Parameter2 and so on.

This is a problem for me because if I need to add 1 parameter I have to create another service with almost the same functionality but using the new parameter i.e:

http://myserver.com/WSFunction/Parameter1/Parameter2/Parameter3

My idea is to call always the same Web Service but passing the version of the Service and a JSON with all the parameters that I need, but as far as I know, I have to warp the JSON in the message (maybe this is not the right word, and that is maybe why I can't find anything in Google), so at the end I will finish with something like:

http://myserver.com/WSVersionNumber/[SerializedJSON]

And in the server I will have a logic like this:

Case:"Version 1"

Deserialize JSON and use Parameter1 and Parameter2

Case:"Version 2"

Deserialize JSON and use Parameter1 and Parameter2 and Parameter3

At the end what I want is to do something like this in iOS:

```
-(NSData *)getMainMenuJsonData{
    NSString *urlAsString = @"http://myserver.com/WSVersionNumber/"

    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:2.5];

    [urlRequest setParameterName:@"SerializedJSON" withValue:SerializedJSONVar];

    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSUInteger statusCode = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode;

    if (statusCode == 200 && error == Nil) {
        if (error != Nil) {
            return Nil;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
    else {
        return Nil;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this in iOS?, I'm not interested in doing this with a third party library because is the enterprise policy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer posted by Tejas Patel that lead me to the right information.

The code ended like this:

```
-(NSData *)getLogin:(NSMutableDictionary *)pData {
    NSString *tUrlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@/%@/GetLogin",[_Configs valueForKey:@"wsURL"], [_Configs valueForKey:@"wsVersion"], [_Configs valueForKey:@"clientToken"], [CommonsUtils getCommonUtil].getAppLanguage];

    NSString* tWebStringURL = [tUrlAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest * tUrlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tWebStringURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:2.5];

    [tUrlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [tUrlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSData *tJsonData;
    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:pData]) {
        NSError *tError;
        tJsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:pData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&tError];
        if (!tJsonData) {
            NSLog(@"json Data %@",tError.description);
            return Nil;
        } else {
            NSString *tJSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[tJsonData bytes] length:[tJsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"JSON String %@",tJSONString);

            [tUrlRequest setHTTPBody:tJsonData];

            NSURLResponse * tResponse = nil;
            NSData * tData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:tUrlRequest returningResponse:&tResponse error:&tError];
            NSUInteger tStatusCode = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)tResponse).statusCode;

            if (tStatusCode == 200 && tError == Nil) {
                if (tError != Nil) {
                    return Nil;
                } else {
                    return tData;
                }
            } else {
                return Nil;
            }
        }
    } else  {
        NSLog(@"This Data can't be serialized");
        return Nil;
    }
}
```

At the end you just have to add a JSON inside the setHTTPBody, so in your REST service you have to receive all the nodes of your JSON with the same name for the variables.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Please check, may be this link will helps you,

This example use ASIHTTPRequest, very easy and effective way to deal with JSON.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7928734/4852079